# I cannot get my footer at the bottom of my content properly

Tags: html, css, footer

Here is a link to the the site I am working on. I am for some reason I cannot figure out why. I can get by having a large margin to the top of my footer div. But that would mean I would need several different footer divs for shorter pages.

http://www.bwtdesigns.com/413

I am also having issues adding my code hopefully. You can see what I am missing. viewing the source.

Comment: I don't understand why there is a giant margin on your footer. Why do you need it.

Comment: Your HTML and CSS isn't good. I suggest you start from the beggining. See [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) to learn the basics and then [w3](http://www.w3.org/) and [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: margin was a whole part of the question. I just missed the clear: both;

Answer (score 1):

The floated elements in the `div` with the "wrap" ID need to be cleared. This can be done by giving the `div` the class name "group". Be sure to do this on any parent items throughout your site that have floated elements.

You'll also need to add the following styles to your stylesheet then you can remove the top margin from your footer.

If you only need to support IE8 and up use this:

```
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Otherwise, use this:

```
.group:before,
.group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
.group:after {
    clear: both;
}
.group {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell that well looking at your code, but I imagine you have a lot of floated elements.
Right before your footer add this:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Tell me if that changes anything. Or add `clear: both;` to the footer.

**EDIT**
I just added:

```
.footer {
  margin-top: 0;
  clear: both;
}
```

to your code using FF developer tools and it fixed it. Read up on Floats and the clear CSS property.

Comment: That seems to fix it. I really apperciate it. I have been staring at this all afternoon. Trying to realize what I forgot or missed.

Comment: Floats can be a HUGE pain until you really understand how they work. I would read up on them. http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101 explains pretty well.